# Jobs ad job offer redirecting to company page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, advertising

I tried clicking on one of the job offers in this ad and the page it redirects me to is the company page instead of the job offer.

[image: job ad]

Wouldn't it be better that when you click the job offer it opens the job page instead of the company page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Clicking on one of those jobs now takes you directly to that job. It took a while because it required re-working a little bit of our analytics, and it wasn't a top priority, but it's done now. Hopefully the behavior will be less surprising for future users.

---

The entire advertisement is for a company, and therefore links to the company page. However, that being said, we are considering adding unique click targets for the individual jobs on them. I think it probably makes sense.